# Cordova Local Webserver Plugin - local host is blocked (iPadOS / iOS) by Content Restrictions

Tags: cordova, localhost, webserver, cordova-plugins, ipados

We have an app that uses Cordova and the Cordova Local Webserver Plugin.  Opening the start page index.html is accomplished using a localhost call to the plugin (something like http://localhost:xxxxx/index.html where xxxxx is the port number randomly chosen by the plugin).  Sometimes our app runs on a device with Content Restrictions enabled and a limited set of URLs added to the Allowed Websites list, including http://localhost.

Starting with iPadOS 16.5, our call is to http://localhost started being restricted even though it is included in the Allowed Website list.  Has anyone else encountered this scenario?

Several combinations of http://localhost, with : or / or wildcard * added, were added to the Allowed Website list with no success.  If http://localhost:xxxxx/index.html was added, it would work and allow access to the local webserver only if xxxxx was a hard coded port number.  So we are looking into that as a solution, but wonder if there may be some other solution or possible plugin updates.